# FileTransfer with python

Tags: python

Making a simple program that determines the OS and then creates directories in a separate folder. Then takes the Desktop and Documents on the computer and saves it into the newly created directory

Problem is: It does not appear to actually save what is on the actual Desktop into the newly created Desktop folder. But it does create the new folders

```
import os
import shutil
import platform

login = os.getlogin()



# Creates Desktop/Documents directories 
if platform.system().lower() == 'darwin':
    #do Mac shit
    newDesktop = r'/Users/%s/WorkDocs/Desktop' %(login)
    if not os.path.exists(newDesktop):
        os.makedirs(newDesktop)
    newDocuments = r'/Users/%s/WorkDocs/Documents' %(login)
    if not os.path.exists(newDocuments):
        os.makedirs(newDocuments)


elif platform.system().lower() =='windows':
    # do windows shit
    newDesktop = r'C:\Users\%s\WorkDocs\Desktop' %(login)
    if not os.path.exists(newDesktop):
        os.makedirs(newDesktop)
    newDocuments = r'C:\Users\%s\WorkDocs\Documents'
    if not os.path.exists(newDocuments):
        os.makedirs(newDocuments)


else:
    print('Only Mac and Windows are supported')


# Saves Desktop/Documents into previously created directories

if platform.system().lower() == 'darwin':
    os.path.join(r'/Users/%s/Desktop' %(login), r'/Users/%s/WorkDocs/Desktop' %(login))
    os.path.join(r'/Users/%s/Documents' %(login), r'/Users/%s/WorkDocs/Documents' %(login))

elif platform.system().lower() =='windows':
    os.path.join(r'C:\Users\%s\Documents' %(login), r'C:\Users\%s\WorkDocs\Documents' %(login))
    os.path.join(r'C:\Users\%s\Desktop' %(login), r'C:\Users\%s\WorkDocs\Desktop' %(login))
else:
    print('OS could not be determined')
```

Comment: `os.path.join` joins the two strings by a path separator based on the os. You are making the new directories but not copying any files.

Comment: any ..suggestion on how to make it work ?     shutil.copytree     will not work if the directory already exists

Comment: you can delete the destination folder before the copy to ensure it doesn't exist. Otherwise, you might want to look into more sophisticated copy methods like rsync.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) module and `os.path.expanduser('~')`

```
    from os.path import expanduser, join
    import shutil

    home = expanduser('~')

    src_desk = join(home, 'Desktop')
    src_docs = join(home, 'Documents')
    dest_desk = join(home, 'WorkDocs', 'Desktop')
    dest_docs = join(home, 'WorkDocs', 'Documents')
    shutil.rmtree(dest_desk)
    shutil.rmtree(dest_docs)
    shutil.copytree(src_desk, dest_desk)
    shutil.copytree(src_docs, dest_docs)
```